# default value for Select dropdown with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a select input:

```
<select id="duration" name="duration" class="form-control select-lg"
          [(ngModel)]="championship.settings.fightDuration">
    <option *ngFor="let duration of durations"
          [selected]="championship.settings.fightDuration==duration"> 
          {{ duration }} {{ championship.settings.fightDuration==duration }}
    </option>
</select>
```

I have his value within `championship.settings.fightDuration`

I try to preselect it with:

```
[selected]="championship.settings.fightDuration==duration"
```

I in select text, I print the result of this condition, and it prints `true` on the element that matches the values, so it should work, but select has no selected value...

What am I missing ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `[ngValue]` as below

```
<option *ngFor="let duration of durations" [ngValue]="duration"> 
      {{ duration }} {{ championship.settings.fightDuration==duration }}
</option>
```

Working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-default-value-for-select-dropdown-with-angular-6)

Comment: It should be `[ngValue]="duration"`.

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro I edited my answer, as `ConnorsFan` mentioned it should have been [ngValue]="duration"

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still having the problem selecting the default value try this.

Let's say you want the option to select has the value `duration`. I am assuming this option is already in the `items` array.

**HTML**

```
<select name="someName" [(ngModel)]="someModel">
   <option *ngFor="let key of items" [value]="key.value">{{ key.label }}</option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
    class someComponent Implements OnInit {

      someModel;

      ngOnInit() { 
          this.someModel = 'duration';
          this.items = [
                            {value: 'duration', label : 'Duration'}, 
                            {value: 'other', label : 'Other'},
                            {value: 'someOther', label : 'Some Other'}
                          ];
      }
```

**On Submit**

Inside your submit function just call like this to get the selected value.

```
this.someModel
```

Hope this helps someone.

This video helped me though - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZlrORYOl_0